Word order (verb placing)
For the translation:"My mom is resting now," Duolingo forces me to write сейчас мама отдыхает instead of сейчас отдыхает мама. Is there a specific reason for this?
And when I put мама сейчас отдыхает, it works. Why does the verb have to be in the last position?
Большое спасибо.

I cannot think of any specific reason. Both of these sentences are valid from my point of view. Oftentimes, you can freely reposition words in Russian and preserve the meaning. Frequently, the exact meaning is transferred not through the order of the words in a sentence, but through the intonation while speaking to another person. I'll demonstrate to you that you can express the same ideas with either sentence. Try to read each sentence out loud and put emphasis on the word that is bold.
Сейчас мама отдыхает.
Сейчас отдыхает мама.
Your intention here is to show that your mother is resting at this particular moment.
Сейчас мама отдыхает.
Сейчас отдыхает мама.
Here you mean that it isn't your father who is resting (or sister, etc.), but your mother.
Сейчас мама отдыхает.
Сейчас отдыхает мама.
In the last two sentences you mean that your mother isn't exercising, cooking, or working. She is resting.
In this case, the problem is in Duolingo itself. It just doesn't consider all possible options. Both variants of the sentence are correct, and you can freely think of them as equivalent.
